# Subfig subcaption labels have wrong spacing with KOMAScript and colored labels

Tags: hyperref, subfloats, koma-script

I observe a problem with the labels of subcaptions generated by the `subfig` package. The distance between label and caption is wrong, but only if I change the color with `\addtokomafont` and if the color is the last parameter I change. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\color{blue}}
%\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\color{blue}\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \center
    \subfloat[][Test.]{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
    \quad
    \subfloat[][Test.]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
    \caption{foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: Picture showing the problem.]

(With the standard fonts it is not that obvious as with my font selection, therefore just for clarification: in the picture, a space character is missing between “(a)” and “Test.” and the same for “(b)”) Since exchanging the color selection with the font selection is already a workaround (see commented line in the code), I have no particular problem but I'm interested in why it behaves like that. Also, maybe others observe the problem by only selecting a color which would not lead them to the workaround. Therefore I ask for some clarification about the mechanism and if it can be solved generally.

Since I consider this a bug, but several packages are involved (hyperref, KOMAscript, subfig), to whom should I send the bug report?

Answer (score 2):

The `subfig` package loads `caption`, so it's best to use the features of this package.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bluesf}{\sffamily\color{blue}#1 #2}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subbluesf}{\sffamily\color{blue}(#2)}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{bluecolon}{\sffamily\color{blue}: }
\captionsetup{labelformat=bluesf,labelsep=bluecolon}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=subbluesf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[][Test.]{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
    \quad
    \subfloat[][Test.]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
    \caption{foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\centering` is the correct command to use.

[image]

However, `subfig` behaves badly with `hyperref`, so you might want to consider `subcaption`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{bluesf}{\sffamily\color{blue}#1 #2}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subbluesf}{\sffamily\color{blue}(#2)}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{bluecolon}{\sffamily\color{blue}: }
\captionsetup{labelformat=bluesf,labelsep=bluecolon}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=subbluesf}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering

\subcaptionbox{Test.}{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\quad
\subcaptionbox{Test.}{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}

\caption{foo}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is already given in the question. If the color selection is the only thing to achieve, one could use a command that does not lead to a change in the appearance. E. g., `\color{blue}\null` works in that case or, maybe better `\color{blue}{}` (an empty group).